# Is std::map a good solution?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

All,

I have following task.

I have finite number of strings (categories). Then in each category there will be a set of team and the value pairs. The number of team is finite based on the user selection.

Both sizes are not more than 25.

Now the value will change based on the user input and when it change the team should be sorted based on the value.

I was hoping that STL has some kind of auto sorted vector or list container, but the only thing I could find is std::map<>.

So what I think I need is:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string team;
    double value;
    operator<();
};

std::map<std::string,std::vector<Foo>> myContainer;
```

and just call std::sort() when the value will change.

Or is there more efficient way to do it?

[EDIT]
I guess I need to clarify what I mean.
Think about it this way.

You have a table. The rows of this table are teams. The columns of this table are categories. The cells of this table are divided in half. Top half is the category value for a given team. This value is increasing with every player.
Now when the player is added to a team, the scoring categories of the player will be added to a team and the data in the columns will be sorted. So, for category "A" it may be team1, team2; and for category "B" it may be team2, team1.
Then based on the position of each team the score will be assigned for each team/category.
And that score I will need to display.

I hope this will clarify what I am trying to achieve and it become more clear of what I'm looking for.
[/EDIT]

Comment: *"Then in each category there will be a team and the value."* -- This is confusing me. In that quote, you seem to be saying that each string should be associated with a single team/value pair (I derived this from the key word 'a', and the singular forms 'team' and 'value').  But in your example with the map, you seem to be associating strings with *multiple* team/value pairs (`std::vector<Foo>`).  Please clarify (in the question).

Comment: *"Now the value will change based on the user input and when it change the team should be sorted based on the value."* -- The team?? Form what `Foo` looks like a `team` has only **one** value, so sorting it will be fairly trivial. Also, your `myContainer` is about as generic a name as you can get. We don't know if that is the top-level collection of Categories, of if it represents just *one* category, neither..? Please clarify this question with the requisite details on algorithm and type info.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, English is not my 1 language, but I tried to clarify this point to the best of my abilities. Everything should be set as in the example.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Sorry, this is hard for me to explain in layman English terms. I'm trying to associate the set of Foo with std::string. The problem is that if the Foo.value changes the set/vector/list of Foo needs to be sorted, so that based on which Foo.team is first the processing occur. myContainer is a top level container.

Comment: If i understand that, you want your Foo set's 'identity' based on the team name, but the sort order based on the value field. Is that about right ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes. But if it will be easier and more efficient I can switch. See my reply to Goz below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It really depend how often you are going to modify the data in the map and how often you're just going to be searching for the std::string and grabbing the vector.

If your access pattern is add map entry then fill all entries in the vector then access the next, fill all entries in the vector, etc.  Then randomly access the map for the vector afterwards then .. no map is probably not the best container.  You'd be better off using a vector containing a standard pair of the string and the vector, then sort it once everything has been added.

In fact organising it as above is probably the most efficient way of setting it up (I admit this is not always possible however).  Furthermore it would be highly advisable to use some sort of hash value in place of the std::string as a hash compare is many times faster than a string compare.  You also have the string stored in Foo anyway.

map will, however, work but it really depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: this is a basic projection algorithm. For the category "ABC" I sort my values highest to lowest. The team who has the highest value receives a score of 1, next - 2 and so forth. When user changes the data, the values for selected team will increase then resorting occurs and then score assignment. But for the Category "DEF" the sorting should be done lowest to highest. So as you can see I need the categories to be kept.